# How to correctly use unique_ptr for Polymorphism in multi-thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unique-ptr

class A is basic class, B is A's inheriting class,and q is a queue for unique_ptr(class A) type.I want to get the element from q,and call the special function for those inheriting class.
here is my code:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void doSomeWork(){
        std::cout<< "doSomeBasicWork"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class B:public A{
public:
    void doSomeWork(){
        std::cout<< "doSomeSpecificWork"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<A> p=std::make_unique<B>();
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>> q;
    q.push(std::move(p));
    auto x=std::move(q.front());
    x->doSomeWork();//print “doSomeSpecificWork”
}
```

so as you can see,in single thread everything is fine.But when I rewrite this under multi-thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include<thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>


class A{
public:
    virtual void doSomeWork(){
        std::cout<< "doSomeBasicWork"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class B:public A{
public:
    void doSomeWork(){
        std::cout<< "doSomeSpecificWork"<<std::endl;
    }
};

void producer(std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>>& q){
        Sleep(1000);
        auto a=std::make_unique<A>();
        q.push(std::move(a));
}

void consumer(std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>>& q){
        Sleep(1500);
        auto p=std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
        p->doSomeWork();
}


int main(){
    auto q=std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>>();
    auto t1=std::thread(consumer,std::ref(q));
    auto t2=std::thread(producer,std::ref(q));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

the output will be "doSomeBasicWork" ,Polymorphism is gone.
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: With threads, you use `std::make_unique<A>()`, while in the first case `std::make_unique<B>()`. Vote to close as typo. Also note that `std::queue` is NOT thread-safe. You cannot use it in multiple threads without synchronization. `Sleep()` does not provide that.

Comment: You have a data race, so your program's behaviour is undefined. You need to synchronise the access to the queue, e.g. by locking a `std::mutex`

Comment: `make_unique<A>` always constructs an `A`. If you want to store a pointer to `B` in a `unique_ptr<B>`, then you need to explicitly specify that the variable is a `unique_ptr<B>`, instead of `auto` (you can then construct it in several different ways according to preference). But then one might ask why not just use `unique_ptr<B>` in the container if that's all it'll hold in reality, at which point more context is required.

Comment: Aside: you could `q.push(std::make_unique<B>());`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the root cause is a typo. However, I strongly suspect that the output will be the same. This is because you use `std::make_unique`. This creates a new instance, but with the Base type `A`. You can read about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), the important part being:

> **Constructs** an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr.

To get around this, you would have to template your functions, providing the concrete type to `std::make_unique`

Something like this:

```cpp
template<class TType>
void producer(std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>>& q){
        Sleep(1000);
        auto a=std::make_unique<TType>();
        q.push(std::move(a));
}
```

And, as others have pointed out, you need to use some sort of locking mechanism, otherwise you will get race conditions. Have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: I don't see how templating helps. They want to have a `queue` of `unique_ptr<A>` but to store the result of `make_unique<B>()`. They would need 2 template type arguments at least. Your code only lets them store instances of `TType` in a `queue<unique_ptr<TType>>`, which contradicts what they seem to want. But then why not just hard-code the types, but explicitly construct the right one? Templating with 2 types would just add more complexity for no apparent benefit, if they only ever need this combo of `A` and `B`.

Comment: what about passing a `queue` of `unique_ptr<A>`s and pushing with `std::make_unique<TType>`?

Comment: That could actually work, yeah, unlike the current code. But then why not just push with `std::make_unique<B>`? That is convertible just fine to the `unique_ptr<A>` in the queue. So no template is needed, just the right syntax for creating a `B`.

Comment: I suppose there will be more subtypes of `A` at one point? BTW I have edited my answer accordingly.